# Should new API version supports all apis of older versions also ? [Design question]

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, api-design

I am having a set of apis exposed at `base/api/v1/end-point1`, `base/api/v1/end-point2`, `base/api/v1/end-point3`, etc. These are basically `v1` apis.

Now we're moving on to expose `v2` apis. In this new api version we'll add some new apis, refactor some existing (v1) apis and some apis will remain unaltered.

**So my question is should I expose all the unaltered apis of v1 in v2 also ?**

---

***Example :***

**API V1:**

api/v1/users - remains unaltered

api/v1/feature1 - will change

other end-points...

**API V2:**

api/v2/feature1 - refactored feature

api/v2/feature2 - newly added

api/v2/users - **should I expose this also ?**

---

I think:

I should not : because it's same

I should : because if it's not exposed then client will need to use different api versions(end-points) for different resources.

What are you doing ? What's your view ? Any reference any best practice resources will be much appreciated.

Let me know if this question is not apt for this platform. I'll happy to ask this at appropriate place.

Comment: In regards to REST not the API needs to be versioned but the media-types you exchange as they define the syntax and semantics of the payload exchanged. REST isn't about invoking methods, it's about resource state. If you look at HTML i.e., it was defined to be backwards compatible. So any client understanding HTML 5 does also understand the previous versions. For your RPC-esque view though, it is primarily your choice whether you want backwards compatability or not

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RomanVottner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Each version should be independent of other. The rationale is that once a version of API is released to the public, it is going to behave the same till it gets deprecated. This ensures that the API provided are stable and doesn't break with a different response. Also from an end developer perspective who consumes the API, it is clean and doesn't confuse about remembering multiple versions.

We usually have multiple versioning as mentioned in [SEMVER](https://semver.org/) docs

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.